# Are there any generalizations of continued fractions to approximations of other polynomial equations?

Tags: continued-fractions, algebraic-numbers

One of the more interesting results about continued fractions, is that the continued fraction representation of a number repeats if and only if the number is a solution to a polynomial of degree 2 (or less) in rational coefficients. I was wondering if there exist other ways to represent real numbers that allow for the same but with other degree polynomials.

EDIT: I somehow missed a couple of words.

Comment: I don't know of any generalizations of continued fractions that are specific to your request, but you might look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence, in particular the result referred to there (and proved there) as "Liouville's theorem on Diophantine approximation," which relates the degree of a polynomial satisfied by an algebraic number  $\alpha$ to a particular notion of the approximability of $\alpha$ by rational numbers.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you! Definitely a relevant interesting read ^^

Comment: However, Liouville's theorem is only a bound in one direction, and not a good one.  [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) says that for any algebraic irrational $\alpha$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there are only finitely many rationals $p/q$ with $|\alpha - p/q| < 1/q^{2+\epsilon}$.  Higher degree doesn't mean better approximations, it just means a worse exponent in Liouville's proof.

Comment: Thank you! another interesting read. Given that even this required algebraic geometry, I'm guessing that no generalization (in the sense I wrote in the question) exists.